# Help with SQLPLUS please? How to make SQLPLUS startup with DEFINE `OFF` initially?

Tags: oracle, command-line, batch-file, sqlplus

I have a batch script that invokes PLSQL with connection details, which works fine but I still have to explicitly `SET DEFINE OFF` when I connect. I would like to enhance my simple batch script to pass the SET DEFINE OFF command to SQLPLUS so that once I am connected, I will no longer have to issue that command manually.

```
echo set define off | sqlplus user/pwd@tnsname
```

This does not work. I am logged in, and logged out again immediately (output follows):

---

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Jun 15 16:43:17 2009
Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

**SQL> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database** 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.
0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

D:>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or in a file called login.sql in your current directory.

Comment: There are some restrictions on `login.sql` since Oracle 12.2. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65238388/2312935

Answer (score 2):

Put `SET DEFINE OFF` either to the script itself or to `glogin.sql` (found in `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus`)

Comment: Wow, I just learned a new thing - about that glogin.sql file. I would never have looked in. However, I would rather not have SET DEFINE OFF for EVERY time I connect to ANY instance. Just from that batch script. What do you mean by Put SET DEFINE OFF either to the script itself? How? That's just what I am after...

Comment: @MasterPeter: just add a line saying SET DEFINE OFF to the beginning of the script :)

Comment: The glogin.sql file (found in $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus) impacts every user that uses the software in the defined ORACLE_HOME. "g" for "global". Some users of the software might be adversely impacted by a "global" change.