# Sql*plus always returns exit code 0?

Tags: oracle, scripting, sqlplus, exit-code

Whenever I run a sql script using Sql*plus and check for $?, I get 0 even when the script wasn't succesful.

Example

```
#$ sqlplus user/password@instance @script.sql


SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Aug 7 14:20:44 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production

     v$dataf-ile d,
            *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


Disconnected from Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
$ echo $?
0
$
```

I would like it to return a non-zero value when an error occurs.

**How can I achieve that ?**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell `sqlplus` to do that, in your script. Basically, there are two statements that you can use:

- `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE`
- `WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT`

For example:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
begin
  SELECT COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

And for OS errors:

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
START no_such_file
```

For more information, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm) and [that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve051.htm).

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: EDIT - The default exit code with WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT is 0 (SUCCESS), so some other option must be explicitly specified. I added the FAILURE option.

Answer (score 7):

Vlad's is the answer I'd use.  To augment his, however, I try to use an explicit EXIT statement if I really need that return status.  For example

```
column status_for_exit new_value exitcode noprint
select status_computation (parm, parm) as status_for_exit from dual;

exit &exitcode;
```

Answer (score 6):

The best action might a combination of the other ideas on this page and the ideas at

[Help with SQLPLUS please? How to make SQLPLUS startup with DEFINE `OFF` initially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996864/help-with-sqlplus-please-how-to-make-sqlplus-startup-with-define-off-initiall?rq=1)

Make a login.sql file, or edit the global one to have

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
```

inside it.
Then, if the file doesn't exist, it will error out. If a line fails, it will error out.

However, keep in mind that as the docs say at : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm#SQPUG135
that certain commands still will not error out as you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, things have changed in Oracle 12.2 according to these [blog](https://mikedietrichde.com/2017/04/17/security-change-in-oracle-database-12-2-with-login-sql/) [articles](https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-12cr2-changes-for-login-sql/).

`login.sql` will be silently ignored unless you set explicitly

- on Linux : `ORACLE_PATH`
- on Windows : `SQLPATH`

to the directory where `login.sql` can be found.

Comment: Doesn't look like your answer has anything to do with the question.

Comment: @JohanBoulé Indeed. I guess it was a comment and it's been turned into an answer (?) then lost the context. Or my original answer has been truncated, or moved from a loosely related question...