# Executing Sqlplus via .bat always returns 0

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is my code. I want to get only 0 if the database connection is successfully else 1. But sqlplus.exe always returns 0.

I call the file sqlplus with the parameter user,password and databasename. After this i try to get the exit code which should be 0 if the connection was successfully but it always returns 0

```
call exit | C:\app\client\sahi\product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN\sqlplus.exe
%DBUser%/%DBPassword%@%DBName% 
if errorlevel 0 (
                 echo successfull
                 goto success
                )
```

**How can i do this?**

Comment: `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` means "if errorlevel is zero or greater": http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/if.mspx?mfr=true  you need a `if errorlevel 1 goto failure`

Comment: The return value always is 0 it is independent of succesful/unsuccessful connectivity.

Comment: If you check like that, then yes the value will always *appear* to be zero.

Comment: how can i check the connectivity ? have you got a idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql\*plus always return exit code 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111517/sqlplus-always-return-exit-code-0)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to check for errorlevel 0:

```
if not errorlevel 1 (
                 echo successfull
                 goto success
                    )
```